# Display Database for Clients in Library

Tags: database, windows, ms-access

I'd like to display the data of my Access database on a separate monitor for the students of a library.

What software or Access tool should I use for this please?

The database should be the only thing the students have access to, meaning they can't access other apps on the computer.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**: relying on your Access app being on the separate monitor is NOT AT ALL secure if you need to prevent user access to other applications (for so, so many reasons, but press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for an example).

**Secondly**: Microsoft Access will open up on the same monitor on which it was last open. Though I assume you know that and wouldn't be asking if that were suitable to you.

**Thirdly**: here is VBA code that actually moves the Access application window. It DOES NOT determine where the second monitor is - you have to change the value `-1500` according to the screen specs (either manually and hard-coded, or better, Google for some code to determine the position of the second monitor). On my setup, it `-1500` happens to end up around the middle of the second monitor which I happen to have on the left (possibly unusual?). If your second monitor is on the right, then I think you'll need a positive value that is greater than the resolution of the fist monitor. It just has to be somewhere within the second screen - not necessary perfectly on the edge because the code then maximises the window. Upshot: you need to experiment with that.

What it does:

1. Take window out of maximised mode (necessary to move it properly).
2. Move it such that the top-left corner is somewhere in the second screen.
3. Maximise the window.

VBA:

```
Declare Function winapi_ShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmd As Long) As Long
Declare Function winapi_MoveWindow Lib "user32" Alias "MoveWindow" (ByVal hwin As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal fRepaint As Long) As Long
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Public Sub MoveAccessWindow
    winapi_ShowWindow Access.Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_SHOWNORMAL  
    winapi_Movewindow Access.Application.hWndAccessApp , -1500, 0, 1000, 1000, True
    winapi_ShowWindow Access.Application.hWndAccessApp, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED 
End Sub
```